# opinions sought: architectural blueprints for instance level security

Tags: java, spring, security, architecture

Context

1. An commerce market where sellers list Items
2. There is an operation Item::setPrice
3. The seller of an item OR a customer service representative can change the price of an item.
4. The security check for #3 is implemented close to the data access layer for the item in order to maximize the coverage for the security check.

Lot's of folks like to talk about security as an *orthogonal concern* but I'm (currently?) not on board with that especially when thinking about instance-level security because that is inexorably tied to the domain model. The bottom line is, I actually *prefer* that the security invariant in #3 be explicitly stated in the code (either via code or by Spring Security EL annotations). I consider such security invariants to be part of the business logic. I also want security in the developer's face. It is not orthogonal to their responsibilities IMO.

I might write something like:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('CSR_ITEM_WRITER') or #item.seller.id == principal.id')
public void setPrice(Item item, Money price) { ... }
```

I realize this creates a certain amount of inflexibility when it comes to evolving the security model (but is that such a bad thing considering the implications of getting it wrong?)

We also discussed approaches where the CS Rep has to "become" the seller. There's a certain cleanliness to that (in that is really focuses the security model around the domain rather than the use cases). *(N.B. sufficient auditing would be put in place to detect when someone is acting on behalf of another)*

Opinions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it exactly right.  When you say security is an orthogonal concern, orthogonal to what?  You are 110% right when you say this should be part of the business logic.

I would keep the separation between the REP and the SELLER.  Both are unique roles; they happen to have overlap for this particular case.

Given the level of importance for security in this context, I would expect you would write a sh*t storm of unit tests that demonstrate the appropriate result given the roles attached to the option.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is a good idea (i'm currently doing something similar).

I would advice you to take a look at the PermissionEvaluator Component in spring security (see [here](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/03/spring-security-by-example-securing.html)) as it has some advantages over plain annotation

1. your security mechanism can be changed easier as it is much more global
2. security evaluation can easily be extended with audit logs/monitoring/...
3. the Evaluator implementation can be unit tested (the annotations require a running spring context to work, so they can only be tested in integration tests)

so far i have found no direct drawbacks of this idea.